# Basic CSS DIV puzzle

Tags: css, html, border

I have a simple HTML page as follows :-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="div1">
      <form>
         <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Col1</td>
            <td>Col2</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is :-

```
div#div1 table,td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

div#div2 table,td {
    border: none;
}
```

As you can see, div2 is not even used in my HTML, but that is the one that takes effect in drawing the table's borders, when I open the HTML file in browser. Shouldn't it be using the border attribute from div1? Even more strange - If I move the div#div2 above div#div1 in the CSS file, it works fine. Also, it works if I completely remove the div#div2 from the CSS. Am I being silly and missing something pretty basic here?

Thanks !!

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#grouping

Comment: The selectors you use are:div#div1 table and td, and then div#div2 table and td, so basically when you change the position of the first and second selectors in the css, you are defining the td twice, first to show none and then to show a border. table and td are not nested in div#div1 or div#div2. To define the table and td within #div1 you need to explicitly declare the selectors: #div1 table, #div1 td  , and do this for div2 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div#div2 table,td
```

This is two selectors, `div#div2 table` as well as `td`. Get rid of the comma.

```
div#div2 table td
```

Or, if you want to style both the `<table>` and `<td>`s, you'll need to repeat the whole selector.

```
div#div2 table, div#div2 td
```

Comment: Yeah, the comma is the problem. You are styling the tr in both rules. Also, you can just write `#div1 td {}` --- not really any reason to be so specific in this case. I would give a class to the table and do `.table-class td`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
div#div1 table td {
border: 1px solid black;
}

div#div2 table td {
border: none;
}
```

You don't need the comma's

Comment: whenever you put any comma, you have to redefine the entire selector. e.g. div#div1 table, div#div1 table td {border:1px solid black}

Comment: you are correct and as someone above pointed out you could just do #div1 td and #div2 td there is a lot of extra in there that isn't necessary.